# Error 405: The resource doesn't support specified http verb

Tags: azure, vuejs2, axios, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on a vue.js tutorial posted on https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-handle-file-uploads-in-vue-2 I'm trying to modify the upload website to work with a Microsoft Azure storage blob. However, after I've modified a file called "file-upload.service.js", I get a 405 error: the resource doesn't support specified http verb I've checked the CORS settings: 
ALLOWED ORIGINS *
ALLOWED METHODS All http verbs are checked
ALLOWED HEADERS *
EXPOSED HEADERS content-length
MAX AGE 84600

1. I've changed the const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3001'; line to https://XXXXXXXXX.z4.web.core.windows.net/
2. Changed const url = `${BASE_URL}/photos/upload`; to const url = `${BASE_URL}/images`;
3. Changed the line img, { url: `${BASE_URL}/images/${img.id}` }))); to img, { url: `${BASE_URL}/images/${img.id}/${sasToken}` })));

This is the original code:
    // file-upload.service.js

```
import * as axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3001';

function upload(formData) {
    const url = `${BASE_URL}/photos/upload`;
    return axios.post(url, formData)
        // get data
        .then(x => x.data)
        // add url field
        .then(x => x.map(img => Object.assign({},
            img, { url: `${BASE_URL}/images/${img.id}` })));
}

export { upload }
```

And this is what the code looks like after the changes:

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://XXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net';
const AccountKey = '?XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

function upload(formData) {
    const uri = `${BASE_URL}/images `;
    return axios.post(uri, formData)
        // get data
        .then(x => x.data)
        // add url field
        .then(x => x.map(img => Object.assign({},
            img, { uri: `${BASE_URL}/images/${img.id}/${AccountKey}` })));
}

export { upload }
```

Expected result: a image would be uploaded to the storage blob
actual result: error 405: the resource doesn't support specified http verb

```
{
  "data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Error><Code>UnsupportedHttpVerb</Code><Message>The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.\nRequestId:4d9b12be-e01e-0060-759b-1dfd43000000\nTime:2019-06-08T01:46:25.1276517Z</Message></Error>",
  "status": 405,
  "statusText": "The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.",
  "headers": {
    "content-length": "237",
    "content-type": "application/xml"
  },
  "config": {
    "url": "https://XXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/images ",
    "method": "post",
    "data": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting this error is because the HTTP method to upload a blob is `PUT` and not `POST`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob.

Comment: Okay, so I setup a put request and then setup a request header? BTW, thank you.

Comment: Yes. Instead of axios.post, you should be using axios.put. I believe the only header you would need would be for blob type.

Comment: I've changed the return line to : return axios.put(uri, formData,{headers:{"x-ms-blob-content-type":Image.id}}) . However, I now get a 405 error: the specified resource does not exist. I remember sometime some permission could be setup in the blob itself, but thought I'd better check with you.

Comment: Do you have “images” blob container? You need “x-ms-blob-type” request header as well.